# What is the equation describing a three dimensional, 14 point Star?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I need to model a 14 point star.  This is a three dimensional surface where there is a point at each of the eight corners of a cube and each of the six sides.  The object is uniform (i.e. planar symmetry).  This is a real object.  It has a volume of 5000 $cm^3$ per side.  The cube in which it sits has 22 cm per side. I need the math to describe it.

---

I went ahead and created the surface using MATLAB, here is the code:

> Grad = 300;
>   A = 1.005748;
>   B = 1.862402;
>
> XAXIS = zeros(Grad*Grad,1);
>   YAXIS = zeros(Grad*Grad,1);
>   ZAXIS = zeros(Grad*Grad,1);
>
> ThetaMax = 2*pi;
>   PhiMax = pi;
>   V = 1;
>
> for n = 1:Grad
>      Theta = (n-1)*(ThetaMax/Grad);
>      for k = 1:Grad
>          Phi = (k-1)*(PhiMax/Grad);
>          L = sin(Theta)*cos(Phi);
>          M = sin(Theta)*sin(Phi);
>          N = cos(Theta);
>
> XAXIS(V,1) = A*L^3 + B*L*(1-abs(L^2-0.33333)-abs(M^2-0.3333)-abs(N^2-0.3333))^5;
>
> YAXIS(V,1) = A*M^3 + B*M*(1-abs(L^2-0.33333)-abs(M^2-0.3333)-abs(N^2-0.3333))^5;
>
> ZAXIS(V,1) = A*N^3 + B*N*(1-abs(L^2-0.33333)-abs(M^2-0.3333)-abs(N^2-0.3333))^5;
>         V = V+1;
>      end 
>   end
>
> clear('ThetaMax','PhiMax','n','Grad','k','M','N','L','A','B');
>   figure
>   scatter3(XAXIS,YAXIS,ZAXIS)

This produced this image:

[image]

I recognize that what I need to do is integrate this expression and that should be the volume.  I could integrate over Phi or Theta.  Otherwise the integral3 command in MATLAB over X, Y, Z should also work.  The goal is to find the bounds of that integral which yields 5,000 cm^3

---

Ok, I got the 14 point star equation to work in MATLAB:

[image]

But, the volume that was put out was about half of what was expected.  This lead me to look deeper into this and I have now learned that the solution I am looking for is a 26-point star.  I have started a new question for this.

[Can someone give me the spherical equation for a 26 point star?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394431/can-someone-give-me-the-spherical-equation-for-a-26-point-star)

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron

Comment: This helps.  Thank you.

Comment: The concept of ["minimal surfaces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) seems appropriate ... except that such surfaces don't have cusps. Perhaps lopping off the tips of the figure to get fourteen roundish border curves, and then investigating what happens as those curves shrink to points, would provide insights. Unfortunately, the calculus of variations isn't my specialty.

Comment: How many corner points has the Mathematica (wolfram) star?

Comment: @Narasimham: The Mathematica star has 20 vertices. It's a representation of a hyperbolic dodecahedron. The OP's figure is combinatorially the dual of the truncated octahedron; aka, the ["tetrakis hexahedron"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrakis_hexahedron). A hyperbolic version of that polyhedron would be close to what OP wants, except (1) it'll have ridges along the "edges", (2) six of its vertices will poke out of the faces of the (Euclidean) bounding cube, and (3) it would be a collection of spherical triangles, not a single surface.

Comment: Your question is not unlike asking, "Here are a couple of (bad) drawings of a real one-pound bird. What's its genome?" There are perhaps a zillion ways to define a mathematical surface *vaguely* like the one you want, and a variety of ways to adjust their volumes to your specifications. (We could make the main body bulge, or adjust the relative thickness of the spikes (in one or the other sets of spikes), etc.) Nevermind that you claim an exact volume but only approximate dimensions. Perhaps if you told us how the figure arose, we can get a better sense of things.

Comment: Also: $x^2 y^2 z^2 = \text{constant}$ **does not** give a "six-pointed star". (Moreover, $(0,0,\pm 11)$ is a solution if the constant is **zero**, not $121$.) For a given (non-zero) $z$, you'd have $x y = \pm k$: a pair of hyperbolas that extend infinitely far in the $x$ and $y$ directions. The surface has eight distinct components ---one per octant--- each of which (for non-zero "constant") forms a cup near the origin and, on the macro scale, very closely hugs the three coordinate planes. (For constant = 0, the solution set *is* the planes!) It's an unbounded figure with no cusps; not a star.

Comment: *"I have an update. Another solution to this surface is: [etc]"* You *do* realize that this new surface you plotted (the multi-colored one) has quite a few more than *fourteen* points, don't you?

Comment: Yes. But I am taking issue with that being the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surface described by the following parametric equations should be close to what you are after:

$$
\eqalign{
&x=\alpha\ l^3+\beta\ l\ (1-|l^2-1/3|-|m^2-1/3|-|n^2-1/3|)^5\cr
&y=\alpha\ m^3+\beta\ m\ (1-|l^2-1/3|-|m^2-1/3|-|n^2-1/3|)^5\cr
&z=\alpha\ n^3+\beta\ n\ (1-|l^2-1/3|-|m^2-1/3|-|n^2-1/3|)^5\cr
}
$$

where:
$l=\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $m=\sin\theta\sin\phi$, $n=\cos\theta$,
$\alpha=3(243+\sqrt{3})/{730}$,
$\beta={324}(3 \sqrt{3}-1)/730$,
while $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the usual angular coordinates on the sphere:
$0\le\theta\le2\pi$ and $0\le\phi\le\pi$.

The embedding cube has edges of length 2, but of course you can multiply everything by 11 if needed. Here you can see a plot of the above surface, made with Mathematica.
[image]

Comment: I've just edited my reply adding constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so that the 14 points of the star now exactly lie at the corners of a $2\times2\times2$ cube and at the center of its faces.

Comment: This is a magnetic surface.  The actual solution is:

Comment: Doesn't that meet your requirements?

Comment: @ThePolywellGuy: "The actual solution is:" ... well?