# Can someone give me the spherical equation for a 26 point star?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

This is the object that I am trying to find the volume of.

[image]

This can be treated as a "26 point star".  What I need is an equation to describe it.  If anyone has that surface in spherical coordinates R(Phi,Theta) that would be awesome. If not, the X,Y,Z solution can also be worked with.

This is a follow-up to work I was doing here:

[What is the equation describing a three dimensional, 14 point Star?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369041/what-is-the-equation-describing-a-three-dimensional-14-point-star)

Comment: How did you get that picture?